# Cómo realizar una sumatoria sin utilizar ciclos (while, for)

Tags: python

Hasta el momento solo se me ha ocurrido que puedo utilizar el método `range()` pero, no sé como efectuar una suma de todos los valores ingresados en ese rango.

Comment: Bienvenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida te invito a leer [mcve] y editala

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ocupar el método `sum()`

*Ejemplo:*

```js
arreglo = [1, 3, 4, 5]

resultado = sum(arreglo)

print(resultado)

#Resultado será 13
```

Comment: El método sum() hace que mi lista se sume toda y la va acumulando?, tengo este programa de la siguiente forma:

'''
Enunciado del problema
Haga un programa que sume todos los números del 1 al 200.

Llamado de librerías (no se utilizaron)
Definir variables globales
'''
lista=list(range(1,201))

print('\nLa suma de los números entre el 1 y el 200 es: {0}'.format(sum(lista)))

Comment: Si, el método te sum() suma toda tu lista de valores (un array)

Comment: Jhon el built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) acepta cualquier iterable (que pueda ser sumado loǵicamente) , lo que incluye a `range` directamente, no necesitas la lista para nada si solo quieres la suma: `suma = sum(range(1, 201))` retorna la suma de todos los números entre 1 y 200 ambos incluidos (20100),

Comment: Listo muchísimas gracias.

Comment: puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta para que los otros usuarios vean que lo resolvistes